# Grid Element expand animations using CSS

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have the following

```js
setTimeout(function(){
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section'), main = document.querySelector('.grid-container'), 
//section = sections[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
section = sections[1];
section.classList.add('expand');
section.parentElement.classList.add('expand');
main.classList.add('expanding');
}, 2000);
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing : border-box; 
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
}

.grid-container {
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid-row, .grid-container {
  
  overflow:hidden;
}

.grid-column, .grid-row {
  display: flex;
  transition: width .2s, height .2s, margin .2s, transform .2s;
}

.grid-column {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:green;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:orange;
}
.grid-row:nth-child(2) .grid-column:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:violet;
}

.grid-row:nth-child(2) .grid-column:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:brown;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .grid-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .grid-column {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  
  .grid-row.expand .grid-column {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
 
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  .grid-row {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .grid-column {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-height: 500px) {
  .grid-row {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.expanding .expand {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-row" data-index="1">
  <section class="grid-column" data-index="1">
    <article>
      <p>
      1
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-column" data-index="2">
    <article>
      <p>
      2
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-row" data-index="2">
  <section class="grid-column" data-index="1">
    <article>
      <p>
      3
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="grid-column" data-index="2">
    <article>
      <p>
      4
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

that I'm trying to develop where the "cells" in the grid that when expands to full area of the view will animate to as if its "pushing" the adjacent elements out of the view.

I'm trying to use a combination of width, height and transforms to give the appropriate animation but the transforms seem to give some unexpected results...

Is there a way to accomplish this WITHOUT `position:absolute` or with as little javascript as possible??

Comment: It is **unclear what you're asking**. Yes, it's possible to do it without JavaScript. Question is: **when**? Do you want it to happen after a set time interval or on some user interaction? You can achieve both without JavaScript but first you have to define the requirement. Also, you should place your code in a stack snippet inside the question, so your question remains relevant even after you change or delete the fiddle.

Comment: What does *"the transforms seem to give some unexpected results"* mean? What are the expected results? Please be specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example seemingly doing what you want, coded from scratch, without any JavaScript. I used flexbox instead of grid, but it can be achieved with grid as well. I used `:hover` as a trigger:

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid>*:hover, 
.grid>*>*:hover {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.grid>*>*:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 7px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 2px 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
.grid:hover>*:not(:hover) {
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid>*,
.grid>*>* {
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

.grid {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid,
.grid>* {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.grid>* {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid>*,
.grid>*>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid>*>* {
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  outline: 1px solid #ddd;
  opacity: .95;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can play around with `flex-grow`, change animation or the ratio between hovered and non-hovered elements but, for that, you need to define the requirements better than *"seem to give some unexpected results"*:

You can obviously limit it to 2 + 2 elements. I just wanted to point out it's flexible in terms of structure. Here's an example, expanding to full on both vertical and horizontal:

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid>*:hover, 
.grid>*>*:hover {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.grid>*>*:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 7px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 2px 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
.grid:hover>*:not(:hover) {
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid>*:hover>*:not(:hover) {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid>*,
.grid>*>* {
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

.grid {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid,
.grid>* {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.grid>* {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid>*,
.grid>*>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid>*>* {
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  outline: 1px solid #ddd;
  opacity: .95;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Generally, I'd avoid going full width/full height, as it makes selecting another item way more difficult.

Comment: Gheorghi This is exactly the effect I'm looking for with the exception that the "hovered" element should expand to the whole width and height of the viewport....Will look at the `flex-grow` definition

Comment: @Kendall, it's a bit tricky, as you also need to define `flex-basis` and `flex-shrink` so the animations do not jump. I added it to the answer. Expanding full should, generally be avoided, unless you provide the controls over what should be expanded elsewhere, as it makes selecting another item difficult, especially when you have more than 2 items per row or more than 2 rows, but that's more of a UX problem.

Comment: I see. Why `flex-basis` and not `flex-shrink`?

Comment: See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ypLa97tc/) about the UX problem. Ref `flex-basis`, I think it could be achieved without it, but for some reason the animation jumps from 0 to content width when starting to expand. Haven't spent too much time on it, since it works after defining `flex-basis`. I'm lazy, by nature :D