# CSS Animation grid flex wrapped expand smoothly, return original when closed

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I want a grid of tiles when clicked on single tile it expands and occupies the whole width and auto height and rest of the unclicked cards to animate and hide. when clicked again the grid tile should collapse and take its place in the grid. I am adding css class selected and not-selected to determine.

Desired output would be to animate to parent top and expand full width and height fit to content. when clicked again to animate shrink to original position

**Current Output:**

[image]

The problem is that css width animation is laggy when entering and exiting. Is there a way to do with transform translate or flex transitions

**Stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-81s3a5?file=style.scss

Comment: In my opinion, no. You will be far better of with using javascript. Something like GSAP will save you time and make the animation pretty smooth.

Comment: can be done check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270714/grid-element-expand-animations-using-css